# Mail bounced during relay via Google account

Tags: linux, postfix, google

I want to all mails form my server to be relay through my private google email account.
But all email are bounced and the return mail stands:

```
I got info: <test.user@domain.com>: host smtp.gmail.com[173.194.69.109]
said: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1
support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 fc7sm2465531bkc.3 - gsmtp
(in reply to MAIL FROM command) - so in such configuration MAIL FROM must be
included in relay definition. How can I do it?
```

How and in which file i have to add line to define MAIL FROM parameter.

Below my main.cf file

```
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/README_FILES
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
command_directory = /usr/sbin
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
mail_owner = postfix

# listen on localhost only
inet_interfaces = 127.0.0.1
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
biff = no
mynetworks = 192.168.0.0/24

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

#Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
delay_warning_time = 4h

relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
```

And how to make port 25 (at this moment nmap show it is not open) be active to receive mail from my local network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inet_interfaces = 127.0.0.1` says to only listen on localhost.  Change that as appropriate to get it listening on port 25.

I'm going to guess that /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd isn't quite right, but I'll need to see the contents to be sure.  Make sure to mask out your real password! :)

Comment: Hmmm. My /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd file contains -->  [smtp.google.com]:587     my_account@gmail.com:maypass and it looks to be good. Whats wrong? I done postmap sasl_passwd as necessary.

Comment: I think that the problem is in "MAIL FROM command". But maybe I am wrong..

Comment: "smtp.gmail.com" and "smtp.google.com" aren't the same, so it won't match anything from your smtp_sasl_password_maps.

Comment: Oh s*&^*t ! In /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd was [smtp.google.com]:587 instead [smtp.gmail.com]:587. Sometimes is terribly difficult to find out such simple error. THX! WORKS!

Comment: Great!  Mind marking my answer as accepted, so others can see what worked for you?

Comment: OK, maybe stupid question. How to accept? I dont see any mark to click on :-(

Comment: There should be a checkmark next to my question.  I would expect this to be more helpful, but it's not really: http://serverfault.com/help/answering

Comment: I think, its done!